# Как можно упростить?

Tags: python

> Пользователь вводит строку произвольной длины. Найти в строке самое длинное слово, в котором присутствуют подряд две согласные буквы. Если в строке присутствует слово с тремя согласными буквами подряд - завершить выполнение.

```
user_input = input('Enter here: ')

splited_user_input = user_input.split()

consonant_list =['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g','h','j','k',
                 'l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','z']

long_word = ''
add_word = ''

for word in splited_user_input:
    counter = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter in consonant_list:
            counter += 1
        if counter == 2:
            add_word = word
        if counter == 3:
            add_word = 0
            break
        if letter not in consonant_list:
            counter = 0
    if add_word == 0:
        break
    if len(add_word) > len(long_word):
        long_word = add_word
if add_word == 0:
    pass    
else:
    print(f'The longest word with the couple consonants: {long_word}')
```

Подскажите как можно упростить?

Comment: Вот только не говорите, что в питоне нет регулярных выражений...

Comment: если использовать регулярно findall то тогда оно будет искать буквы а не слова (если я не ошибаюсь)

Comment: Проверяете `re.match('[qwrtpsdfghklzxcvbnm]{3,}', word)` на окончание, если нет, то `{2}` на две согласных.

Comment: @Akina я где-то туплю ? *Проверяете re.match('[qwrtpsdfghklzxcvbnm]{3,}'* разве  qwr не подойдет? тогда уж `([qwrtpsdfghklzxcvbnm])\1\1` ?

Comment: @splash58 Подойдёт. В задании не сказано, что две/три согласные должны быть одинаковыми.

Comment: @Akina ах ты черт, тогда мой ответ неправильный, я не так понял задание

Comment: @splash58 Пофиг. Автор принял. Пусть теперь попробует сдать...

Comment: @Akina  :) спасибо! день как-то не очень начинался, а теперь прям норм

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать смотреть сразу повторы букв в слове

```
user_input = input('Enter here: ')

consonant_list =['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g','h','j','k',
                 'l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','z']

longest_word = ''

for word in user_input.split():
    for cl in consonant_list:
        if cl*3 in word:                
            longest_word = ''
            break
        if cl*2 in word:
            if len(word) > len(longest_word):
                longest_word = word  
if longest_word == '':
    pass    
else:
    print(f'The longest word with the couple consonants: {long_word}')
```

Comment: спасибо, куда короче

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант:

```
import sys

input_str = input('Enter here: ')
consonant_list =['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g','h','j','k',
                 'l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','z']

out, flag = '', 0
mod_input = sorted(input_str.split(), key=len, reverse=True)
if bool([cnsnt for cnsnt in consonant_list for word in mod_input if cnsnt*3 in word]):
    sys.exit(0)
for word in mod_input:
    for cnsnt in consonant_list:
        if cnsnt*2 in word:
            out, flag = word, 1
            break
    if flag:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Упрощённая версия вашей программы:

```
import sys

user_input = input('Enter here: ')    
splited_user_input = user_input.split()    
consonants = set("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz")    
long_word = ''
add_word = ''

for word in splited_user_input:
    counter = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter in consonants:
            counter += 1
        else:
            counter = 0

        if counter == 2:
            add_word = word

        if counter == 3:
            sys.exit()

    if len(add_word) > len(long_word):
        long_word = add_word

print(f'The longest word with the couple consonants: {long_word}')
```

**2)** Также, для сквозного выхода из двух циклов можно обернуть весь код в  функцию и использовать команду `return`. Здесь, в отличие от предыдущей версии, просто завершается код поиска максимального слова, программа продолжает работу.

```
def find_max_word():
    user_input = input('Enter here: ')

    splited_user_input = user_input.split()

    consonants = set("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz")

    long_word = ''
    add_word = ''

    for word in splited_user_input:
        counter = 0
        for letter in word:
            if letter in consonants:
                counter += 1
            else:
                counter = 0

            if counter == 2:
                add_word = word

            if counter == 3:
                return ''

        if len(add_word) > len(long_word):
            long_word = add_word

    return long_word

result = find_max_word()

if result:
    print(f'The longest word with the couple consonants: {result}')
```